# Unable to open a tar.gz file

Tags: linux, unix, tar

Are there any alternative ways to open a ".tar.gz" file than `-xzf` or `-zxvf` or `xzvf`? I am running Mac OS X 10.7.

My command line returns:

```
tar: Unrecognized archive format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

I am doing this to open `mysql-5.1.33.tar.gz` from a sites method to install MYSQL. I have tried many methods to open the tar and something wrong. What I am not seeing?

Comment: Try just unzipping it first, and ensure it's a valid tar file.

Comment: This isn't a suitable question for stackoverflow. Perhaps http://unix.stackexchange.com/. While you're here, what does 'file' tell you about the archive?

Comment: unzip with `gzip` first, then use `tar`.

Comment: .. and what does `file` tell you about the archive, once you've unpacked only it?

Answer (score 6):

I would guess that the archive is damaged. Try downloading it again, and even controlling the checksum if an intended value is given at the download site if it does not work.

If it still does not work, try

```
gunzip mysql-5.1.33.tar.gz
```

to see if the compression is done correctly, and then

```
tar xvf mysql-5.1.33.tar
```

to try to unroll the archive. This will pin point the problem better.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it turned out that when I had downloaded the .tar.gz file, I had clicked "Download Link" on a page that led to a second page with the actual download.

So, my .tar.gz was just a bunch of HTML.

You can check by posting the address of the .tar.gz in your browser to make sure it's an actual compressed file.

Comment: Thanks for this idea. My problem was that the actual file (that I'd tried to curl) didn't exist anymore, so my tar file was actually a 404 page.